# Extracting n values from a nested JSON within a TSV column

Tags: python, json, pandas

Given this:

| cat | size | cat_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fluffy | medium | { "cats": { "catVariety": ["calico"], "age": [], "colors": ["orange", "black", "white"] } } |

I need the following:

| cat | size | catVariety | age | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fluffy | medium | calico | NULL | orange black white |

Assume I have thousands of rows like this. How can I use python to render this without any pre-processing? There are many other ways this could be accomplished but I need to use python and have been unable to figure out how to parse the JSON for an entire column.

Comment: `cat_json` is a string or a dict?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure json_normalize or other built in parsers will work due to the way you want to the lists broken out. This assumes there will always be a list as each value and the three keys will always be there. Otherwise, you just need more logic in the function.

```
data='''cat     size    cat_json
fluffy     medium       { "cats": { "catVariety": ["calico"], "age": [], "colors": ["orange", "black", "white"] } }'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df

def parsejson(x):
    x['catVariety'] = ' '.join(json.loads(x['cat_json'])['cats']['catVariety'])
    x['age'] = ' '.join(json.loads(x['cat_json'])['cats']['age'])
    x['color'] = ' '.join(json.loads(x['cat_json'])['cats']['colors'])
    return x
    
df.apply(parsejson, axis=1)

     cat    size                                           cat_json catVariety age               color
0  fluffy  medium  { "cats": { "catVariety": ["calico"], "age": [...     calico      orange black white
```